# Compare each element in a list to all others

Tags: python

Is there a way to compare all elements of a list (ie one such as [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]) to all others and return, for each element, the number of other elements it is different from (ie, for the list above [6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6])? I then will need to add the numbers from this list.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add the numbers from this list'? Do you want to `sum` them, or something else?

Comment: I mean, from the resulting list [6,7,7,7,6,7,7,7,6] I will want to  add 6+7+7.... to yield the sum of the elements in the list

Answer (score 3):

```
li =  [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(li)
print c
length = len(li)

print [length - c[el] for el in li]
```

Creating `c` before executing `[length - c[el] for el in li]` is better than doing `count(i)` for each element i of the list, because that means that `count()` do the same count several times (each time it encounters a given element, it counts it)

By the way, another way to write it:

```
map(lambda x: length-c[x] , li)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get similar counter with `count()` method.
And subtract the total number.
Do it in one line with a comprehension list.

```
>>> l = [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
>>> [ len(l)-l.count(i) for i in l ]
[6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7:

```
test = [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
length = len(test)
print [length - test.count(x) for x in test]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `sum` function, along with a generator expression.

```
>>> l = [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
>>> length = len(l)
>>> print sum(length - l.count(i) for i in l)
60
```

The good thing about a generator expression is that you don't create an actual list in memory, but functions like `sum` can still iterate over them and produce the desired result. Note, however, that once you iterate over a generator once, you can't iterate over it again.